# Fixing Sass / SCSS bracket indentation

Tags: css, regex, formatting, sed, sass

I have a regex puzzle for you all!

A week or so ago, I decided to change the formatting of my Sass file from this:

```
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover: {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}

div { ... }
```

To this:

```
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover: {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline; } }

div { ... }
```

The second syntax seems nice -- it saves you lines and improves readability -- but it is actually a disaster for writing code. Imagine if I wanted to add another line after a:hover's text-decoration: I'd have to bring those two parentheses with me.

Anyway, I've been trying to find the perfect regex to change the formatting back but to no avail.

My thinking:

1. Match and capture 2 spaces since all closing brackets are indented at least one level: `(\s{2})`
2. Match and capture all additional spaces: `(\s*)`
3. Match and capture all other characters (my CSS code): `(.*)`
4. Match space + closing bracket: `}`

Replace that with two lines:
`\1\2\3\n\2}`

Doesn't exactly work quite yet. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Obligatory "CSS/SCSS is not a regular language" blabber.

Comment: Didn't know that. My CS professor would be furious.

Comment: Why not use SASS instead of SCSS? It supports all the same features, but has no verbose `{ }` characters -- It's more like Python in that respect, and closer to what your new style resembles

Comment: Have thought of that. Looking into it but would still love a solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex won't really work, as you've discovered, because the meaning/desired position depends on the parsing of the Document that has come before.

You need a parser or a filter for this job.

Fortunately, a standard [JS beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/), or a [CSS indenter](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier) should whip that file right back into shape.

PS:  Also consider more frequent backups and version control. (^_^)

Comment: Of course I'm using version control, but I've been making changes for a week and it could potentially be a pain merging them in with the old syntax and new syntax.

Comment: Used Tabifier with C-style. Got it to a manageable enough form for me to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Another easy way to do it is to do a quick replace on your editor, no regex, just make it match the spaces, replace with the new brackets/lines. Might not be as quick as using a css re-indenter though.

Comment: Do not bump old questions unless you have something meaningful to add.  This does not answer the question in a meaningful way.

Comment: Sorry, I though the side links were newer questions. Did not see the date.

This is an alternate solution though, I always do this when I want to indent some new css file a specific way or fix it. Takes just a few seconds.